# How to align a Paragraph centre vertically

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I have a small paragraph in a page, which I want to align *centre horizontally as well as vertically*.

Aligning centre horizontally is quite straightforward, however I am struggling to find a way to *centre that Paragraph vertically in the page*.

Is there any way, preferably any shortcut to achieve the same?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the paragraph into a text box (or a frame). Both a text box and a frame can be positioned in the (horizontal or vertical) center of the page (or alternatively of the page's text area).

For a text box: Right-click -> Position and Size -> Position.

For a frame: Properties -> Type -> Position.